# Difference between internationalization and generic attributes in html

Tags: html, tags, attributes

This may seem to be a very basic question. But I need some clarification here in this topic.

***In HTML,***

**Generic attributes** - eg: align, bgcolor etc.

**Core attributes**    - eg: id, style etc. (This may be used as main or major attributes needed for any tag)

**Internationalization attributes**  - eg: dir, lang

I also understood that all the above attributes are common to all tags (If I am right), then what is the basic difference between these three attributes?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your concept of understanding between generic and core attributes is fine..

> Internationalization attributes are available for almost XHTML elements

eg.1 Lang Attribute
It focuses specifically on advice about specifying the language of content.

eg.2 Dir Attribute
The dir attribute allows you to indicate to the browser the direction in which the text should flow. The dir attribute can take one of two values.
`ltr` - Left to right (the default value)
`rtl`   Right to left (for languages such as Hebrew or Arabic that are read right to left)
EXAMPLE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<title>Display Directions</title>
</head>
<body>
This is how IE 5 renders right-to-left directed text.
</body>
</html>
```

This will produce following result:

This is how IE 5 renders right-to-left directed text.